# Getting an attribute from json

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to get a specific attribute from a json object. This is my code.

```
require 'json'

def print_f(json)
    json.map do |person|
        puts "\n#{person['name'] }, \n #{person['lastname']}"
    end.join
end

a = '{"JSON": {"name": "Fernando", "lastname": "Soto"}}'

obj = JSON.parse(a)['JSON']

text = ''
text += print_f(obj)
puts text
```

When I do:

```
puts obj.inspect
```

it returns:

```
"`{"name"=>"Fernando", "lastname"=>"Soto"}"
```

But when I try to run it, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from t.rb:14:in `<main>'
        4: from t.rb:4:in `print_f'
        3: from t.rb:4:in `map'
        2: from t.rb:4:in `each'
        1: from t.rb:5:in `block in print_f'
t.rb:5:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You're calling `map` on a hash. If you want to iterate over people your document should have an array of hashes, not just a singular hash. It's also unusual to have a root-level entry like "JSON" in a JSON file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is not a real stuff, I'm just trying to understand how json works in Ruby, thats why I had a json level in a json.
Have an excellent night, greetings.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but in cases like this it's usually best to put together a simple example of what you're actually trying to manipulate. The problem here is using the wrong iterator type.

Comment: Thanks, so can you tell me which is the right iterator just  in case that I need to iterate what I currently have? I would appreciate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only accessing a single record, `map` is not relevant:

```
def print_f(json)
  puts "\n#{person['name'] }, \n #{person['lastname']}"
end
```

If you did want to iterate over them then you'd need to change your document to this:

```
a = '{"JSON": [ {"name": "Fernando", "lastname": "Soto"}} ]'
```

That's an array of objects (Hashes) so `map` then applies.

Another thing I've noticed is if you're intending to return a string `puts` is the wrong way to do it. Instead you want:

```
def print_f(json)
  "\n#{person['name'] }, \n #{person['lastname']}"
end
```

This is because `puts` always returns `nil` regardless of input.

Comment: I did it finally, thank you so much tadman, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

well this is how it works, just in case someone else needs this specific example, hope you find this example useful. Special thanks to tadman.

```
require 'json'

def print_f(json)
    json
    json.map do |person|
        "\n#{person['name'] },\n #{person['lastname']}\n#{person['name2'] },\n #{person['lastname2']}"
    end.join
end

a = '{"key1": [{"name": "Fernando", "lastname": "Soto" ,"name2": "Luis", "lastname2": "Bautista"}]}'


obj = JSON.parse(a)['key1']

text = ''
text += print_f(obj)
print text
```

And this is the result.

```
Fernando,
 Soto
Luis,
 Bautista
```